# Aggregated counts for Releases

Tags: rally, appsdk2

With items like the Portfolio Item, there are fields which represent aggregated totals for the child elements which parent to them. For example, "LeafStoryCount" and "LeafStoryPlanEstimateTotal". I recently started a project working with Releases which requires me to gather similar information, yet I've found that these fields are not available.  Ideally, I would like a way to query for all Releases within our workspace, while ignoring those that have no work assigned to them. Is there any way to do this with the API, or would the only solution be to gather the User Stories, and then aggregate counts for each release?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you are correct, fields similar to  "LeafStoryCount" and "LeafStoryPlanEstimateTotal" are not available for Release object.